Implementing Complex Graphics in Flutter: Code-Only or Require External Images?
I'm currently working on a Flutter project and aiming to recreate a specific visual effect/design within my app. Something similar to this https://i.sstatic.net/HoT6p.jpg from Trivia Crack.
Is it feasible to implement this entire design using Flutter's native drawing capabilities (e.g., CustomPainter, ShaderMask, ClipPath)?
What are other Flutter widgets or packages that could help me achieve this? or would it be more practical to use external images (e.g., SVG, PNG) for some parts of the design?
I've did this but I does not look aesthetically pleasing.
class RightAnswerCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final int answersCount;
  final String price;
  final bool isBestValue;

  RightAnswerCard({
    required this.answersCount,
    required this.price,
    this.isBestValue = false,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 120,
      height: 160,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.white, // Card background color
              elevation: 4,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    // Placeholder for the right answer icon. Use an actual image in your asset
                    Icon(Icons.emoji_events, size: 40, color: Colors.green),
                    Text(
                      '$answersCount',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    // This container is for the price tag at the bottom of the card
                    Container(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 8.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[200],
                        // Light grey background for the price
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                            4), // Rounded corners for the price tag
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        '\$$price',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          if (isBestValue)
            Positioned(
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Best value',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  static Widget buildSection(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> rightAnswersOptions = [
      {'answersCount': 3, 'price': '1.99', 'isBestValue': false},
      {'answersCount': 8, 'price': '4.99', 'isBestValue': false},
      {'answersCount': 16, 'price': '9.99', 'isBestValue': false},
      {'answersCount': 32, 'price': '19.99', 'isBestValue': false},
      {'answersCount': 85, 'price': '49.99', 'isBestValue': false},
      {'answersCount': 180, 'price': '99.99', 'isBestValue': true},
      // Add more options if necessary
    ];

    return Container(
      color: Colors.green[100],
      // Assuming a greenish background as in the image
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              'Right Answers',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          GridView.builder(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            // to disable GridView's scrolling
            shrinkWrap: true,
            // You won't need to set the height manually
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3, // Number of columns
              crossAxisSpacing: 8, // Horizontal space between cards
              mainAxisSpacing: 8, // Vertical space between cards
              childAspectRatio: 0.8, // Aspect ratio of the card
            ),
            itemCount: rightAnswersOptions.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return RightAnswerCard(
                answersCount: rightAnswersOptions[index]['answersCount'],
                price: rightAnswersOptions[index]['price'],
                isBestValue: rightAnswersOptions[index]['isBestValue'],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

https://i.sstatic.net/COcMO.png

I assume you mean the greenish selected effect?  That's just a simple gradient applied to the background.  If you mean something else, be more specific with what you're having trouble with

It would be more practical to use external images in many cases and also time saving.
